# Dell Lattitude E5400 CD Burner not working

Tags: drivers, dell, burning, cd-ripping

When I go to burn a audio CD it says error. I'm not even sure if I have the drivers for it.

Can someone help?

I'm on 13.10 by the way.

Comment: Can you add the error message ?

Answer (score 0):

That's strange have you checked your bios and in-program options? I know on my Dell Inspiron 6400 laptop with DVD Decryptor I had to make sure my bios settings were right and I had to change the in-program power options to get it to work. Also is this a DVD/CD drive, cd drive, or dvd drive? I had a toshiba satellite laptop that the dvd drive refused to work before i configured it with dvd decryptor. Keep me posted on your progress. :3

Comment: the disk tray says RW DVD-Re-writable. I'm not sure about BIOS settings as I am unfamiliar with it.